# Reactive Extensions Throttle produce no results

Tags: system.reactive, reactive

Given this setup,

```
public static class NotifyPropertyChangedExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>> WhenPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged source)
    {
        return Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
            ev => source.PropertyChanged += ev,
            ev => source.PropertyChanged -= ev);
    }
}

public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (_isChecked != value)
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}

nodes.Values.Select(node => node.WhenPropertyChanged())
            .Merge()
            .Where(x => x.EventArgs.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            .Subscribe(x =>
            {
                // do somethings
            });
```

why does this not fire any events when I call?
    nodeX.IsChecked = true;
immediately after setting up the subscription but works afterwards?

Comment: It  would be nice if you can expand the posted code so it actually compiles and can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that is the intended behavior of the `Throttle` operator:

> only emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item

([source](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html))

So in your case, since you perform the `Merge` before applying the `Throttle` operator, an item is emitted after a change to `IsChecked` *and then* after 200 ms.